# Cuando utilizar métodos estáticos?

Tags: método

estoy empezando en esto de la programación y no me queda muy claro cuando utilizar los métodos estáticos , podríais ponerme algunos ejemplos donde estaría mejor utilizar un método estático que un método normal? Por lo poco que sé , veo más cómodos los métodos estáticos ya que no hay que crear un objeto para llamarlos

Comment: a que lenguaje te refieres?

Comment: @wuasaa Especifica el lenguaje al menos, hay lenguajes que no trabajan con clases  con métodos estáticos...

Answer (score 1):

Los metodos estaticos sirven para no instanciar los objetos y luego utilizar sus metodos, tienen muchos usos desde patrones de diseno
hasta la funcionalidad de librerias.

te dejo unos ejemplos:
la libreria `Math` muy utilizada, no necesita crear el objeto Math, se puede utilizar importandolo y directamente hacer referencia a sus metodos
aunque se tambien se puede utilizar de la otra forma, creando el objeto Math  e invocar a sus metodos.
haz la prueba:

paso 1: importa la libreria Math

paso 2.1: por ejemplo usa su metodo `Math.sqrt(2);// solo invocas la clase y usas el metodo`
o

paso 2.2:

```
Math m=new Math();
m.sqrt(2);
```

**Adicionando informacion:**

La palabra reservada static es usada para crear constantes asi:
public static final constante=1;

cuando crear una variable con la palabra reservada static mantiene su valor llamado tras llamado, por ejemplo cuando tienes una variable contador
que tiene un valor 10, y refrescas tu panel(solo es un ejemplo) esa variable mantiene su valor, ***si lo llamas desde otra clase mantendra su valor, se puede considerar como una variable global de toda tu aplicacion.***

Comment: Error, `static` no es para crear constantes, el valor de una variable con `static` puede cambiar, el de una constante no.

Answer (score 1):

La idea de las variables o métodos estáticos es representar valores/funciones de uso global y que no sea particular de una instancia.

Por ejemplo, las variables **firstname**, **lastname** son particulares de una instancia, sin embargo la variable **roles** (array con roles posibles) sería de uso global, en cambio la variable **rol** si es particular de la instancia pues representaría el rol que tiene el usuario.

Sorry, soy un poco complejo para explicar.

Si utilizas PHP el ejemplo sería

```
<?php

class User{

  public static $roles = ['admin', 'user', 'teacher'];
  protected $rol;
  protected $firstname;
  protected $lastname;

  public static function roles(){
    return self::$roles;
  }

  public static function rolesNotAdmin(){
    $roles = self::roles();
    unset($roles[0]);

    return $roles;
  }

  ...
}
```

para llamarlo dentro de la misma clase/instancia puedes usar la palabra reservada **self** seguida de dos puntos y el nombre de la función o variable: **self::roles()** o **self::$roles**.

Cuando necesitas llamarlos desde fuera de una instancia solo debes nombrar la clase seguida de dos puntos y el nombre de la función o variable **User::roles()**:

```
<?php

$roles = User::roles(); 
$rolesWithoutAdmin = User::rolesNotAdmin(); 
$roles = User::$roles; // la variable es accesible por que la dejamos publica ;)
```

Espero te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que utilizas Java.
Método estáticos de una clase en Java:

- Se cargan en memoria en tiempo de compilación y no a medida que se ejecutan las líneas de código del programa. Van precedidos del modificador static.

Ejemplo:

```
public static void contadorUniversal (){
    numContadorUniversasl++;
}
```

Para invocar a un método estático no se necesita crear un objeto de la clase en la que se define.

- Si se invoca desde la clase en la que se encuentra definido, basta con escribir su nombre.
- Si se le invoca desde una clase distinta, debe anteponerse a su nombre, el de la clase en la que se encuentra seguido del operador punto (.) .metodoEstatico

Suelen emplearse para realizar operaciones comunes a todos los objetos de la clase. No afectan a los estados de los mismos (a los valores de sus variables de instancia).

Ejemplo, si se necesita un método para contabilizar el número de objetos creados de una clase, tiene sentido que sea estático ya que su función (aumentar el valor de una variable entera) se realizaría independientemente del objeto empleado para invocarle. Ejemplo contadorUniversal

No conviene usar muchos métodos estáticos, pues si bien se aumenta la rapidez de ejecución, se pierde flexibilidad, no se hace un uso efectivo de la memoria y no se trabaja según los principios de la Programación Orientada a Objetos.